# Trying to do calculations using Date and Time in R. Which function to use for my specific calculation?

Tags: r, datetime

I am doing a case study on bike share. Trying to calculate the time spent (in minutes) by each user  , which would occur by subtracting the end time by start time.

[image]

I first tried to create new start_time and end_time columns .After which I can do calculations, using the following commands:

```
df_cyclistic_copy$started_at_time <- as.POSIXct(df_cyclistic_copy$started_at_datetime, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
df_cyclistic_copy$ended_at_time <- as.POSIXct(df_cyclistic_copy$ended_at, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```

A column is created but with NA

[image]

I even checked the class of the new started_at_time column. It is POSIXct

[image]

I do not understand. Where am I wrong? (Note: I am new to programming in general)

Comment: Your columns are already in the correct format.  No need for `format` there

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Answer (score 0):

The columns are in the default format for Datetime, i.e . ymd hms.  We just need to use `as.POSIXct`.  The `format` if need to be specified, it would be `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` instead of `"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"` as the string starts with 4 digit year (`%Y`) followed by `-` then 2 digit month (`%m`), `-` , 2 digit day (`%d`)

```
df_cyclistic_copy$started_at_time <- as.POSIXct(df_cyclistic_copy$started_at_datetime)
df_cyclistic_copy$ended_at_time <- as.POSIXct(df_cyclistic_copy$ended_at)
```

as an example

```
> as.POSIXct("2022-04-06 8:52")
[1] "2022-04-06 08:52:00 EDT"
```